# Unable to run andorid app in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

Starting the android studio gives this error

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72220Library'.
>   Could not expand ZIP '/home/abskpr/Android/Sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/22.2.0/appcompat-v7-22.2.0.aar'.

Please help!!!

Comment: Open your "app" gradel and remove the appcompact dependency to check if that works and compile.

Comment: I think you lack permissions for the project in your OS. Try running the android studio as administrator.

Answer (score -1):

It's a build error; Go to **File** -> **Settings** -> **Build** -> **Gradle** and select **Use default Gradle wrapper (Recommended)**

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but a new error was generated.

Comment: Error:No route to host

Comment: Could you post your project's build.gradle?

Comment: // Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.2.3'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

Comment: That's not the one, look for this: [image](http://s14.postimg.org/wf9d8fopt/build_gradle.jpg)